# How to change my css to make hyper link visible [ with minimum sample code ]?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a site with CSS, but the hyper links are not visible [ right side ], how to change my html/css so that the hyper links are visible [ like the left side on the follow image ] ?

[image]

I've simplified my site to show the problem and here is the minimum sample code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>GATE Cyber Technology : Award Winning Innovation For Identity And Access Management</title>
    <meta name="description" content="GATE Cyber Technology LLC. INTERCEPTION-RESISTANT AUTHENTICATION AND ENCRYPTION SYSTEM AND METHOD. Introducing a breakthrough digital security innovation : Graphic Access Tabular Entry [ GATE ], an interception-resistant authentication and encryption system and method. With the GATE system you are not afraid that you are watched when you enter passwords, and you are not afraid that the password will be intercepted, the GATE innovative method is designed to be peek-resistant and interception-resistant. The GATE system and method will offer you better digital security. Identity and Access Management (IAM)">
    <meta name="keywords" content="GATE Cyber Technology LLC. INTERCEPTION-resistant AUTHENTICATION AND ENCRYPTION SYSTEM AND METHOD, Graphic Access Tabular Entry [ GATE ], GATE security, GATE authentication, GATE login, GATE user authentication, GATE password, GATE passcode, peek-resistant, online security, digital security, passwords, password protection, strong password, strong cybersecurity, strong user authentication, prevent password loss, prevent user credential loss, passcode, cyber security, pin, login, logon, digital access, online access, access control, online protection, digital protection, online defence, digital defence, message encryption, message decryption, signal encryption, signal decryption, overcome weakness of traditional password, the GATE system, award winning, better than fingerprinting, better than iris scanning, safer than keyfob, better than password manager, safer password entry, Identity and Access Management (IAM), GATE defeats wiretapping, keylogging, peeking, phishing and dictionary attack, no restrictions of traditional password's lowercase, uppercase, numbers and special characters requirements, easy to use">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="cXY5hsdt7XCjR_k96nha7Hn5uW4fw_1u6mc2LWDyAQ0" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.ahrefs.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,100italic,100,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic">
    <link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.ahrefs.com/assets/css/home-responsive.css?20180815-001">

    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
    <link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/home-responsive.css">

    <meta property="og:image" content="GATE_1.PNG">

    <style>
      div.Intro
      {
        font-size: 100%;
        text-align: left;
      }

      div.Table
      {
        font-size: 218%;
        text-align: center;
      }

      a:hover { color:#ddeeff; }
      a:visited { color:#E8E8E8 }
     
      tr a{ font-size: 18px;color:#aabbcc; }
      tr a:hover { color:#ddeeff; }

      .pic-container-1{display:block; position:relative; }
      .pic-container-1 .pic-box{display:block;}
      .pic-container-1 .pic-box img{display:block;}
      .pic-container-1 .pic-hover{position:absolute; top:0px; left:104px; display:none;}
      .pic-container-1:hover .pic-hover{display:block;}

      .pic-container-2{display:block; position:relative; }
      .pic-container-2 .pic-box{display:block;}
      .pic-container-2 .pic-box img{display:block;}
      .pic-container-2 .pic-hover{position:absolute; top:0px; left:18px; display:none;}
      .pic-container-2:hover .pic-hover{display:block;}

      .pic-container-3{display:block; position:relative; }
      .pic-container-3 .pic-box{display:block;}
      .pic-container-3 .pic-box img{display:block;}
      .pic-container-3 .pic-hover{position:absolute; top:0px; left:20px; display:none;}
      .pic-container-3:hover .pic-hover{display:block;}

      .pic-container-4{display:block; position:relative; }
      .pic-container-4 .pic-box{display:block;}
      .pic-container-4 .pic-box img{display:block;}
      .pic-container-4 .pic-hover{position:absolute; top:0px; left:18px; display:none;}
      .pic-container-4:hover .pic-hover{display:block;}

      #GATE_Frame_1 { width: 78%; height: auto; }
      #GATE_Frame_2 { width: 98%; height: auto; }

      #Balance { width: 80%; height: auto; }
      
      #Ted_Murphree_img { width: 36vw; height: auto; }
      #Scott_Schober_img { width: 36vw; height: auto; }
      #Cary_Pool_img { width: 36vw; height: auto; }
      #Eduard_B_img { width: 36vw; height: auto; }
      #Jonathan_Rosenoer_img { width: 36vw; height: auto; }

      #Traditional_vs_GATE_1 { width: 96%; height: auto; }
      #Traditional_vs_GATE_2 { width: 99.5%; height: auto; }

      #modal
      {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        max-height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(24, 24, 24, .6);
        z-index: 999;
      }
      #modal .content
      {
        position: relative;
        width: 55%;
        height: 65vh;
        margin: auto; /* allows horyzontal and vertical alignment as .content is in flex container */
      }
      #modal .content .yt-video
      {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 45px);
      }
      #modal .content .title
      {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 23px;
        padding: 12px 4px;
        margin: 0;
        background: #007bff;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 26px;
        max-width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
      #modal .close
      {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 36px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 38px;
        color: #fff;
        background: #366;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background .2s;
      }
      #modal .content .close .a { font-size:38px;color: #ffffff; }
      #modal .close:hover, #modal .close:active { background: #ff0000; }
      #modal.is-visible { display: flex; }

      html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
      fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video
      {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }

      /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
      article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
      body { line-height: 1; }
      // ol, ul { list-style: none; }
      blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
      blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
      q:before, q:after
      {
        content: '';
        content: none;
      }
      table
      {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="page__guest ahrefs page-home">
    <div id="localizejs">
      <div class="content">
        <a id="Awards"></a>
        <div class="datas">
          <div class="container center">
            <Table Cellpadding=6>
              <Tr>
                <Td Align=Center><Br>
                  <Font Color=white><A Href=http://bestech.ittn.com.cn/#/projectlist2021 target=_blank>GATE has been selected</A> to the <A Href="2021_ZGC_Top_100_List_1.PNG" target=_blank>top 100</A>,<Br> among more than 2800 technologies collected<Br> from all over the world at 2021 ZGC<Br><A Href=http://bestech.ittn.com.cn/#/home target=_blank>International Technology Trade Conference</A>.</Font>
                </Td>
              </Tr>
            </Table>
          </div>
        </div>

    <!-- the modal div that will open when an anchor link is clicked to show the related video in an iframe. -->

    <div id="modal">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="close"><a onclick = "return close_iFrame();">&times;</a></div>
        <h4 class="title">.</h4>
        <iframe class="yt-video" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var modal = document.getElementById('modal'),
          closeBtn = modal.querySelector('close'),
          ytVideo = modal.querySelector('.content .yt-video'),
          title = modal.querySelector('.content .title'),
          anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-target="modal"]'),
          l = anchors.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
      {
        anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function (e)
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          title.textContent = this.dataset.videoTitle || 'No title';
          ytVideo.src = this.href;
          modal.classList.toggle('is-visible');
          modal.focus();
        });
      }

      modal.addEventListener("keydown", function (e)
      {
        if (e.keyCode == 27)
        {
          title.textContent = '';
          ytVideo.src = '';
          this.classList.toggle('is-visible');
        }
      });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function close_iFrame()
      {
        var modal = document.getElementById('modal'),
            ytVideo = modal.querySelector('.content .yt-video');

        ytVideo.src = '';
        modal.classList.toggle('is-visible');

        // Opera 8.0+
        var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

        // Firefox 1.0+
        var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

        // Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
        var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);

        // Internet Explorer 6-11
        var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

        // Edge 20+
        var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

        // Chrome 1+
        var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;

        // Blink engine detection
        var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;

        var output = 'Detecting browsers by ducktyping :\n===========================\n';
        output+='isChrome: '+isChrome+'\n';      // 57.8 % Market Share
        output+='isSafari: '+isSafari+'\n';      // 14.0 %
        output+='isFirefox: '+isFirefox+'\n';    // 6.0 %
        output+='isIE: '+isIE+'\n';
        output+='isEdge: '+isEdge+'\n';          // 5.9 %  IE + Edge
        output+='isOpera: '+isOpera+'\n';        // 3.7 %
        output+='isBlink: '+isBlink+'\n';

//        alert(output+'[ history.length = '+history.length+' ]');

        if (isChrome)                            // 57.8 % [ Will work correctly only after 3rd+ time of going to the #Videos section ]
        {
/*
[1] No code : after 1st play, "back" plays sound
              after 2nd play, "back" also plays sound, remembers history
              after play 2 videos, 1 "back" plays last vodeo, 2 "back" does nothing, 3 "back" plays 2nd last video
              Seems to remember [ empty ] + [ video ]

Memory pattern : Top [video_1] [ ] [video_2] ?
*/

          if (!sessionStorage.getItem("runOnce")) // 1st time : Remembers 1st video  // 2nd time : back to top after closing iFrame  // 3rd time+ : works correctly
          {
            // alert('runOnce');
            window.history.replaceState({},"Videos","#Videos");
//            window.location.href='#Videos';
//            history.go(0);
            sessionStorage.setItem("runOnce",true);
          }
          else
          {
            window.history.replaceState({},"Videos","#Videos");
            history.go(-1);
          }

        }
        else if (isSafari)                       // 14.0
        {

        }
        else if (isFirefox)                      // 6.0 % [ Works correctly ]
        {
          history.go(-1);
        }
        else if (isIE)
        {
            window.history.replaceState({},"Videos","#Videos");
        }
        else if (isEdge)                         // 5.9 %  IE + Edge
        {
            history.go(-1);
        }
        else if (isOpera)                        // 3.7 %
        {
            history.go(-1);
        }
        else if (isBlink)
        {
            history.go(-1);
        }
//alert( window.location.href );
//        history.go(-1);
//window.location.href = '#Videos';
//history.replaceState({}, "#Videos", "#Videos");
//alert( window.location.href );
      }

      window.onload = function()
      {
        // Opera 8.0+
        var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

        // Firefox 1.0+
        var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

        // Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
        var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);

        // Internet Explorer 6-11
        var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

        // Edge 20+
        var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

        // Chrome 1+
        var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;

        // Blink engine detection
        var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;

        var output = 'Detecting browsers by ducktyping :\n===========================\n';
        output+='isChrome: '+isChrome+'\n';      // 57.8 % Market Share
        output+='isSafari: '+isSafari+'\n';      // 14.0 %
        output+='isFirefox: '+isFirefox+'\n';    // 6.0 %
        output+='isIE: '+isIE+'\n';
        output+='isEdge: '+isEdge+'\n';          // 5.9 %  IE + Edge
        output+='isOpera: '+isOpera+'\n';        // 3.7 %
        output+='isBlink: '+isBlink+'\n';

//        alert(output);

        if (isIE) 
        {
//          alert(output);
          var pichover=document.getElementsByClassName("pic-hover");
          pichover[0].style.left="107px";
          pichover[1].style.left="24px";
          pichover[2].style.left="23px";
          pichover[3].style.left="21px";
       }
     }


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but 375 lines of code, half of which is JavaScript is in no way "minimum" for such a basic CSS question. According to your profile, you've been around and involved on this site more than long enough to realise that this is not a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out with the hint from @Ki [ THANK YOU VERY MUCH ^_^ ! ]

Although your answer didn't show the solution DIRECTLY, but it pointed me in the right direction, so with more research and test, I finally got to the right conclusion, your answer is MUCH MORE helpful than someone else's comment that I've been here for too long to not realize this and that, I don't even want to repeat what was said [ waste of time ! ]

a:link { color:#d8d8d8 ; text-decoration: underline }

**This question and answer WILL be useful to other people who has similar problems !**

Answer (score 1):

but this is bad

```
a[href] {color: blue !important, text-decoration: underline !important}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 